# Is there a link between nuclear radiation and sound?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acoustics, radiation, atoms

I'd like to understand if it's possible to relate/imagine a link or relationship between nuclear radiation and sound. A simple description would be appreciated since I don't have a deep understanding of nuclear radiation or sound

From what I gathered through some research, Sound and nuclear Radiation (not electromagnetic) are two completely different phenomenons. One is related to atoms while the other is related to sound pressure waves travelling through a medium.

It might pose as a strange question but what I would like to know (I am an artist trying to imagine a connection), is if it would be possible to imagine nuclear radiation and sound in a similar way? Would it be possible to relate the two? Even if scientifically there is no basis....I would like to be able to imagine some type of correlation between the two.

If so how would it be possible?

Comment: Note that if you go directly to the point, it will be easier to read to your question and you are more likely to get an answer. No need to excuse yourself or use pompous language ;)

Comment: The program PRA (Pulse Recognition and Analysis) can be set to play a note at every gamma photon detected, with a frequency proportional to the detected energy.

Comment: sorry, I don't mean to offend anyone here. Just looking for a possible correlation between the two.

Comment: @zwigiding nah, nobody's offended :) It's just that concise stuff are easier to read. I've edited the post a bit to cut out some of the bits which gave a bit too much background; could you see if that's OK?

Comment: Hi @Pieter, thank you so much for pointing that out to me! That's amazing how the software can transform a PC sound card into a powerful multi channel analyser for gamma spectrometry. This is definitely very interesting indeed! Will look into it further.

Comment: Hi @Chair, thanks for that. I just updated your edit.

Comment: My answer assumed electromagnetic radiation was what was being talked about, but once I posted I noticed the question had been edited to refer to nuclear radiation... @zwigiding what was your original intent?

Comment: @TheLedge The [revision history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/433923/revisions) makes it clear that OP introduced that change themself.

Comment: @TheLedge yes you're right, I meant nuclear radiation indeed and not electromagnetic radiation. Thank you so much for your post. It helps me to understand electromagnetic radiation and sound. It will be useful to know this too.

Comment: @Pieter could I imagine the relationship between sound and radiation via the proportional frequency of the photons detected energy?

Comment: I do not think it sounds good at all. But one of my students was interested in exploring this kind of experimental music. Quite random notes with random intervals.

Comment: [Geiger counters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter#Readout) often have an audio output.

Comment: @Pieter you're right it probably won't sound good. Depends on the parameters set to indicate the sounds. If the sounds chosen and reflect harmonically something meaningful, it could sound nice! Apparently by using the gamma spectroscopy software, one can recognise simple radioactive sources by listening to the sound. For example it is possible to recognise 54Mn, 57Co, 60Co, 133Ba, 109Cd, and 137Cs using NaI detector.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks, that's interesting! Using the G-M detector to translate the rouge electrons. This could be something interesting to look at indeed. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to relate the two?

No. Nuclear radiation, particularly alpha and beta radiation, consists of physical objects which come flying off of the radioactive material. Gamma radiation consists of high-energy photons coming out.

In contrast, sound is a collective phenomenon: it consists of regions of high pressure and high density expanding and pushing on neighbouring regions in an oscillatory fashion, which propagates as a wave.

**There is no link between the two.**

> I would like to be able to imagine some type of correlation between the two.

That's not a reason for such correlation to exist. The world is the way it is and physics is there to describe it, not (as you suggest) the other way around.

Comment: Hi Emilio, thank you for taking the time to point it out simply and clearly. Yes I imagine that this is a truly strage question seeing that physics has already affirmed their differences. I was just trying to imagine in a poetic way...how the two phenomenons could possibly interrelate. Perhaps as energy?

Comment: @zwigiding Sorry, I thought you were looking for a physics answer - the physics answer is **no**. If you're looking for a "poetic way" (which, by your usage, presumably means "ignore as much of the physics as necessary until none of the differences are left"?) this is not the venue.

Comment: Yes I realise that my question is inprecise and thank you so much for clarifying the difference between the two :D

Answer (score -1):

**Electromagnetic radiation** and **sound** are both [**wave** phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave). Waves are used to describe physical situations where energy is transferred between two points through a medium without displacement of the medium.

**Sound waves** are vibrations, or oscillations, in the molecules making up our air (or whatever substance the sound travels through). The source of the sound vibrates with a tiny back and forth movement. This pushes the molecules closest to the source back and forth, which push the next closest molecules back and forth, which push the next ones, etc... There is no overall displacement of air (the molecules originally affected at the source stay close to the source, they don't travel to your ear), but energy is transferred through the air via oscillations. For a visualization, look at this gif:

[image: sound wave animation]

If you watch any individual molecule, it will never move far from it's original position. The wave is just an area of higher density, and this is what transfers the energy.

**Electromagnetic waves** are orthogonal oscillations in the [electric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field) and [magnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) fields (hence the name). In this case, it is the magnitude of the electric and magnetic fields that change and oscillate. Again, nothing is actually moving, but the oscillations transfers energy from one point to the next. Here is a good way to visualize the oscillations of the electromagnetic fields:

[image]

Here, the red wave is the electric field and the blue wave is the magnetic field.

Because electromagnetic radiation and sound are both wave phenomena, they can be described mathematically in similar ways. They both have [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency) and [wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength), and are both described by [wave equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation).

Let me know if you'd like more clarification.

Comment: Nuclear radiation is not the same as electromagnetic radiation; OP is asking about the former and not the latter. And, while nuclear gamma radiation does consist of photons, their extremely high photon energy means that attempting to describe them using classical electromagnetic wave theory (instead of quantum electrodynamics) is pretty disingenuous.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty when I wrote the answer the question did not specify nuclear or electromagnetic radiation, and I assumed electromagnetic. I am very aware of the difference. The specification in the question was made later via edit.

Comment: Nevertheless, your answer was posted after the edit. Note that this isn't personal criticism, but it does mean that the answer as provided is off-topic and misleading w.r.t. the question's text at the time this answer was posted; hence the downvotes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I see your point. Would it be better to delete the answer?

Comment: @TheLedge I don't think deletion is necessary - but this would certainly be significantly improved if it drew a clear line between EM and nuclear radiation.